# find empty cells with support for mixed datatypes of lists and sets and ints and str

Tags: pandas, list, nan

Consider the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns =['A','B','C'])
my_df.at[0,'A'] = 1234
my_df.at[0,'C'] = ['5','6','7']
my_df.at[1,'A'] = set([8,9,10])
my_df.at[1,'B'] = 'my_hat'
```

Then I want to find all the cells that are nan.

```
for row_index, row_data in my_df.iterrows():
   for cell in row_data:
      if pd.isnull(cell):
          print("found one")
```

The pd.isnull, pd.isna, pd.notnull all cannot handle the mix of lists/sets with ints/str.

Please note this is a much simplified example, I need to test each cell with an if statement, detecting nans.

Comment: What is the expected output here? (do you want the count? The index (r, c) of nulls? Etc)

Comment: So dose not isnull return what you need ?

Comment: I need to check each cell, one by one, with a conditional statement. I need to act, when I encounter a nan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
If you really need to check each cell for `NaN`, you may do it on `my_df.isna()` such as

```
for row_index, row_data in my_df.isna().iterrows():
   for cell in row_data:
      if cell:
          print("found one")
```

---

Try this to see the output of your for loops. I took out the if line to show all values of `cell` from for loop:

```
for row_index, row_data in my_df.iterrows():
    for cell in row_data:
        print(cell)

Output:

1234
nan
['5', '6', '7']
{8, 9, 10}
my_hat
nan
```

Now try:

```
pd.isnull(['5', '6', '7'])

Out[3183]: array([False, False, False])
```

`pd.isnull` accepts `scalar or array-like` and returns `bool or array-like of bool`. One of your `cell` is array so it returns an array of bool values. Compare truthful of an array of bool values is ambiguous, so pandas just throws error.

If you want to check 'NaN' in `df`, call `isna` or `isnull` directly on `df`

```
my_df.isna()
```

Or you need to call `pd.isnull` on the whole `df`

```
pd.isnull(my_df)

Out[3181]:
       A      B      C
0  False   True  False
1  False  False   True
```

Comment: Yes understood, I can do a .all() on the array [False, False, False].  But this won't work if the cell contents are an int.

Comment: @Joylove: if you really need to check each cell, you may do for loop on `my_df.isna().iterrows()` and doing ` if cell`. check my update